# how to create existing html5 website working offline?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm embedding videos and images is there way to have them work offline?
size of video 202mb-300mb
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photos and videos you can cache using HTML5 (upto 5MB limit per site usually applies depending on browser being used), but data size of 200-300 MBs makes it difficult in your case.
Also if you are caching you would be shown cached version of files. It could be a problem.
You can always download videos and photos to client machine but that is not a clean solution for you I guess.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: how about on app on android or iOS if i was to use webview will it matter or is it same?

Comment: webview is a VIEW (presentation) for your content (which is photos and videos) of size 200-300 MB, if you want it to work offline then you have to have this content locally on your mobile device. App size of 200-300MB (for one video) is very large. It can work if streamed ONLINE.

Comment: how about working with just <video> alone in html5 is there way to have the video continue playing offline?

Comment: only if video is locally stored on device. for that you must have downloaded it.

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html) and [here](http://grinninggecko.com/2011/02/24/developing-cross-platform-html5-offline-app-1/). There are serious restrictions to max cache seize, but it says that safari for mac, android chrome and firefox got unlimited storage. So you can try.

Comment: webview using OS default browser core dll so it will have same restrictions.

Comment: thanks for the links it gives me better understanding what i'm working with :)